# awk unable to remove new line character in a specific column

Tags: awk

I'm trying to remove newline character in the first column in csv file using awk but it doesn't seems to work

Sample File:

```
  "This
  is a test
  ","Something","Something"
  "This is
  another
  test","something","something"
  "One
  more
  test","something","something"
```

The command i'm using is

```
awk -F, '{gsub("\n","",$1); print}' sample
```

The output doesn't remove the new line character

I'm looking for a solution using awk not sed or perl

Can someone please help?

The output required is,

```
"This is a test","something","something"
"This is another test","something","something"
"One more test","something","something"
```

Comment: show how should look the final result

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you have is a CSV exported from Excel or some other windows tool (since that's what it looks like) and so it has `\r\n` line endings, all you need is this with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' -F'\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
"This is a test ","Something","Something"
"This is another test","something","something"
"One more test","something","something"
```

Otherwise with GNU awk for multi-char RS this would work for the sample you posted:

```
$ awk -v RS='"\\s+("|$)' -F'\n' '{$1=$1; gsub(/^"?|"?$/,"\"")}1' file
"This is a test ","Something","Something"
"This is another test","something","something"
"One more test","something","something"
```

Comment: I  tried this it is still showing me everything in  the same line. When i do an octal dump i'm not seeing a carriage return.

Comment: Then my assumption about your input was wrong. Where did you get a CSV from that looks like that? Anyway, I've added a gawk script that'd work for your example.

Comment: You can create a similar csv file when you export windows event logs in csv format. The description for some events contain multiple lines similar to the format i specified above.

Comment: I've never heard of any Windows tool creating CSV or any other text file without `\r\n` line endings, You sure you didn't run `dos2unix` or similar on it?

Comment: This is the command i used to generate the csv files,
$start= Get-Date -Day 12 -Month 03 -Year 2017
$end=   Get-Date -Day 16 -Month 03 -Year 2017

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname="System"; starttime=$start; endtime=$end; } | Export-Csv -Path c:\System-$(hostname).csv